Problem with Simulated ctrl+c Not Updating Clipboard Content Inside a Loop
I’m building a Python program that needs to read clipboard contents that update during each iteration of a loop. I've seen other questions about reading from the clipboard, but none of them seem to work when the content is updated in a loop.
When I try to simulate ctrl+c inside a loop using pyautogui, the clipboard content read is always the first thing I copied, rather than the updated content. I’ve tested reading from the clipboard manually, and it works fine, but the issue seems to be with the simulated ctrl+c not actually copying new content to the clipboard in each iteration.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
from tkinter import Tk
import pyautogui  # Used to simulate keyboard inputs

for i in range(3):
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')  # Simulate copying current selection to clipboard

    # Create an instance of Tk to access clipboard content
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # Hide the Tk window
    clipboard_content = root.clipboard_get()  # Read clipboard contents
    root.destroy()  # Destroy the Tk instance after reading clipboard

    # Process the clipboard content
    operation = clipboard_content.split("+")
    operation = [i.replace('\r\n', '') for i in operation]

    result = str(int(operation[0]) + int(operation[1]))  # Perform addition

    # Simulate typing the result
    for i in range(len(result)):
        digit = result[abs(len(result) - i - 1)]
        pyautogui.press(digit)
        print(digit)


I’ve manually tested the clipboard reading (Tk.clipboard_get()) and it works fine when I manually copy new text.
I’m running the code from VS Code, and I’ve ensured that the text selection changes between iterations.
How can I ensure that the clipboard content updates properly after each ctrl+c simulation inside the loop?

Are you sure it's the clipboard getting and not the simulated ctrl+c that's wrong?

Are you also sure that the selection changes before each iteration of the loop? That is something you could verify with the debugger.

btw, I was trying pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') thrice wondering why it caused error before i realised it wasn't error,but keyboard interrupt.. in IDLE.. You can use time module and a sleep between each iteration since your iteration is not a forever loop(without it the loop ends in milliseconds getting same selection copied everytime)

Thank you for your comments! I've tested the clipboard reading (using Tk.clipboard_get()) separately, and it works fine when I manually copy new text. The issue seems to be with the simulated ctrl+c command. Do you have any suggestions on how to ensure that the selected text has been updated before copying? By the way, I've verified that the text selection changes correctly between iterations, and I'm running the code in VS Code.

You need to wait until the user copies something new to the clipboard. Then run the function that handles this event.

The Ctrl-C should only be executed after the text has been selected. In your loop this is impossible, since it runs too fast.
